# Magento 2.2 blank page after upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

After upgrading Magento from 2.1 to 2.2 I got a weird issue. Site is showing all pages blank on frontend, but admin panel has error "not redirecting properly" and can not be accessed. No errors in logs.

Mode: production; Magento version: 2.2.3 Commerce

Comment: can you please check mod_rewrite module is enabled or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few hours the thing that worked for me was disabling and re-enabling Dotmailer module.

```
php bin/magento module:disable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
php bin/magento module:enable Dotdigitalgroup_Email
```

UPDATE:

Issue was actually caused by incorrectly generated metadata files (at the point of running setup:di:compile there was a symlink created for "generated" folder which somehow made the global.php file to be incorrectly generated). module:enable/disable command made metadata files to be deleted and that is why site started working correctly.

Issue got resoved when we updated deployment procedure and removed "generated" folder symlink before running setup:di:compile.